# What is the alternative for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath in .netstandard 2.0

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, c#-2.0, .net-standard-2.0

What is the alternative for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath in .netstandard 2.0

Comment: What specifically does this return i..e what are you trying to emulate. 
Have you tried any alternatives, or found any resources online that may help in narrowing it down

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `IHostingEnvironment` may be what you aer looking for, documentation guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your answer, It is the application domain configuration information.
I know that's related to AssemblyLoadContext Class in but I can't find the same request as I asked

Comment: I think it may be a little unclear what you are asking, you may need to give an example of what you are trying to emulate, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In fact I was searching for the path of the assembly containing the code:

I found this function That I think can field my need:

```
    public static string AssemblyDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }
    }
```